# Как отправить базу данных Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio19 так чтобы получатель смог открыть ее у себя в ssms на локальном сервере?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, export, ssms

Нужно отправить бд (mydb) [image: бд на локальном сервере которую нужно отправить] либо как-то экспортировать(ввиде файла) чтобы получатель смог ее развернуть на своем локальном сервере. Экспорт а аксес файл не подходит.

Что пробовал:

1. Экспорт данных не подходит
2. Извлечение и отправка (.mdb и .mdf) дает ошибку изза того что локальные сервера разные [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что порекомендуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте резервную копию и перешлите её. А, получатель развернёт её у себя.

Как это сделать описано в доках Microsoft: [Копирование баз данных путем создания и восстановления резервных копий](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/databases/copy-databases-with-backup-and-restore?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: окей. Както уже пробовали .bac отправлять - не вышло (мб гдето не то нажали). Вечером попробуем по инструкции. Тогда оценю ответ :)

Comment: можете и просто файл базы и лога скинуть, а там ее приаттачат

Comment: да все работает.